# Why is my progress bar not incrementing when the form is loaded?

Tags: c#

I have form that I will show below. I want the progress bar to slowly run up on the onLoad event to test to make certain that it works.

Should I be able to just used this code to loop through the progress bar values?

**Question: Why does the progress bar not increment on onLoad()?**

```
         progressBar1.Value = 0; //start at zero value
         int n = 100;

         double progress = 0;

         //This loop should increment the progress bar.
         for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         {
             if (progress <= 100)
             {
                 progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
             }
         }
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestDifferentForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             progressBar1.Value = 0;
             int n = 100;

             double progress = 0;

             for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
             {
                 if (progress <= 100)
                 {
                     progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

1. The value of `progress` never changes
2. You are doing this all on one thread, so the bar won't update until the method is complete.
3. You are just incrementing from 1 to 100 with no work in between, so the incremental updates will be too fast for you to see the bar change.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are never incrementing the value of *progress*. You just set it to `0` and then assign it to value of *progressBar1* again and again.

Answer (score 2):

You are not incrementing `progress` variable. Try this:

```
         for (int progress = 0; i <= n; progress++)
         {
                 progressBar1.Value = progress;
         }
```